# Can ’t add datetimepicker to Tabulator column

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetimepicker, tabulator

I would like to create custom editor for my Tabulator table. I need to edit date values and would like to use jQuery DateTimePicker.

I tried to edit example code from the Tabulator website, but it is not working for me. My custom editor code looks like this:

```
var dateEditor = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
            var editor = document.createElement("input");
            editor.setAttribute("type", "text");

            editor.value = cell.getValue();

            onRendered(function(){
                jQuery(editor).datetimepicker({
                    format: "dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm",
                }); 
                editor.focus();
            });

            function onChange(e){
              success(editor.value);
            }
            editor.addEventListener("change", onChange);
            editor.addEventListener("blur", onChange);


            return editor;
};
```

And column definition:

```
{title:"Date", field:"date", align:"left", headerFilter: "input", editor: dateEditor, headerFilterPlaceholder:" "},
```

Datepicker component shows up but when I try to change the value, following message appears:

> "Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker"

Thanks for your help.

Edit#1: Found out, there was a problem with date format, but main problem still persits.

Comment: Could you post a codepen or a snippet with a working/broken example? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue. The issue is that you shouldn't use the `onChange` or `onBlur` event of the textbox. Rather you want to use the datepicker events

```js
var dateEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){
    var cellValue = cell.getValue(),
    input = document.createElement("input");

    input.setAttribute("type", "text");

    input.style.padding = "4px";
    input.style.width = "100%";
    input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    input.value = typeof cellValue !== "undefined" ? cellValue : "";

    onRendered(function(){
        input.style.height = "100%";
        $(input).datepicker({
            onClose: onChange
        }); //turn input into datepicker
        input.focus();
    });

    function onChange(e){
        if(((cellValue === null || typeof cellValue === "undefined") && input.value !== "") || input.value != cellValue){
            success(input.value);
        }else{
            cancel();
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kcf1jes0/7/

[image: Working fine]